# Got Javascript/HTML and PHP part, how test on mac?

Tags: javascript, php, html, macos

Sorry if this is a repeated question. I've searched but couldn't find any that solved my problem...

I've got javascript code and php code. And I wanna try it, how can I do it on my Mac?

Javascript has a page where I'm supposed to send some numbers to the php, which calculated some stuff and returns it on the page.

The code can be found here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39428424/send-undecided-amount-of-data-to-php-file-javascript-pjp

Comment: tried [phpfiddle](http://phpfiddle.org/)?

Comment: How do I put in the php part?

Comment: Take a look at software such as 'Mamp'

Comment: What you need is to install some PHP server on your Mac. Alternatively, you may find a hosting which supports PHP and put your scripts there. Keep in mind that asking about suggesting a tool is believed off-topic at SO.

Answer (score 0):

https://sourceforge.net/projects/xampp/

xampp is pretty good. Open source and has a decent following

Answer (score 0):

Apache2 + Php5 is pre-installed in macOS, so you need to just put your code in /Library/WebServer/Documents and then open http://localhost/ url in your browser.

Youtube Video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=X3y9rQyxAK8

Comment: Thanks! I'm kinda bad at this, do you know if there's any tutorial that shows me how it's done?

Comment: @GossetStudent just added a youtube video

Comment: Ok, did what he did, and added my files into that folder, but still doesn't work. Any clues?

Comment: Did you started apache as well ?

Comment: Also what macOS version you are using ?

Comment: Did everything he did. El Capitan 10.11.6